# How can I can I make changes to a WP project I pulled from GItHub?

Tags: wp-admin, login

I pulled a Wordpress project down from GitHub and have successfully ran it locally in terms of making the website appear on my browser.

However, I'd like to make some changes to it but I don't know how I could access the WP dashboard so that I can make those changes.  I don't suppose I need a username & password just to have the ability to make changes on the website locally, do I?

It's using the Enfold theme if that matters.  Any suggestions on what I should do?

I've tried:

https://mywebsite.com/wp-login.php

https://mywebsite.com/wp-admin

But they're both giving me `This site can’t be reached` error on the browser.  What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You shouldn't be using the plugin/theme code editor in WP Admin for anything other than emergency fixes, especially if your project is under version control. GitHub is just a `git` service, aside from `git`, the files are just the files, GitHub doesn't host the site, and the files work exactly the same as they did before. I ***strongly*** suggest you download a decent code editor such as VS Code/Sublime/PHPStorm/Atom, and modify the files that way, and that you look up basic git howtos for making commits and pushing/pulling. Again, GitHub has nothing to do with WP usernames and passwords

Comment: Sublime is a particularly good text editor for PHP, in my opinion. The assumes you are running Linux. On windows try Notepad+ because it has formatting options. I'm assuming you have an environment setup such as LAMP or WAMP giving you a local http server, php & mysql. If you are just trying to open php files in your browser, that's never gonna work.